# How to implement semantic versioning in GitLab pipeline step by step

Tags: gitlab, semantic-versioning

I’m trying to implement a semantic version in our GitLab pipeline. I just don’t know where to start and how to start. I am stuck at the moment and have gone through its website https://semver.org, it is more like what it does rather than how it should implement in real-time.

Could anyone guide me or help me understand the step-by-step process to implement the semantic versioning in GitLab.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information regarding the type of project ? Depending on the ecosystem or language you are using there can be different options for tagging and creating releases which is what your versions would be used for.

Comment: @quizguy its a vendor application. we are trying to do software versioning. Currently, we are tagging the images and deployment using commit_short_sha value in a non-prod environment. whereas for prod we are using tagging strategy for production release, wherein the tag is the date of the release date. Next, we are planning to implement semantic versioning on this vendor application/process. I would like to get some insight as to how I would kickstart this process.

Comment: @Learning Did implement this? How?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article on how to [Auto Tag Releases with Semantic Versions](https://rokpoto.com/auto-tag-releases-with-semantic-versions/).

To answer your answer in general:

The developers have to provide the information about the nature of the change (breaking change, non-breaking change, bug fix) to the release pipeline either by MR source branch name, MR label or tag. The release pipeline will auto-generate the semantic version based on that information and store the semantic version in git tags.

Comment: Note: GitLab 16.10 will enforce semantic versioning on its releases: https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/03/21/gitlab-16-10-released/#semantic-versioning-in-the-cicd-catalog

Comment: @VonC, GitLab's new SemVer enforcement policy is only for publishing a new version of a CI/CD Catalog, which is just a special kind of project that you can use in your other CI/CD pipelines to extend functionality of your pipelines. To my knowledge, GitLab does not enforce any kind of versioning policy on your build artifacts, containers, etc, which I think is what OP is interested in.

Comment: @Mattman I agree. This is more limited than what I hoped.